# IBM XL C compiler - how do I expand user includes but not system includes

Tags: c, zos, xlc

Searched all the IBM manuals but surprisingly can't find the answer.
I have the following:

```
#include < stdlib.h>  
#include < stdio.h>   

#include  "userinc1" 
#include  "userinc2"
```

There is a compile option  - which has a default of NOSHOWINC 
If I change this to SHOWINC and recompile - I get everything expanded from all 4 includes above. I only want the user includes to be expanded..

So far not spotted any option to do this - so any help would be appreciated.
This is the IBM XL C compiler running on z/OS.

Comment: What do you mean by "expanded"?  According to this link (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_9.0.0/com.ibm.tpf.toolkit.compilers.doc/ref/user_guide_zos/cbcugmst164.htm%23HDRSHOWINC), the option only specifies whether or not the files processed are displayed as they're processed. If so, the easy solution is to filter out the files you don't want to see with something like grep.

Comment: I want the entire contents of the 'copybooks' in userinc1 and userinc2 to be displayed in the compiler output but I don't want the 2 system .h files to be expanded in the compiler output (many thousand of lines) grep.... This is z/OS not a Unix system!

Comment: The compiler on z/OS does not support selective showing of include files in the source listing. You get all or none.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOWINC=USR
```

should do what you want. At least it does on XL C for AIX.

Comment: No,  SHOWINC on z/OS does not take any parameters.   
Looks like there is no means to accomplish this.